# htaccess: user authentication for specific user agent

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication

Some background information: I have a Qnap NAS and want to use the different stations (basically a server app) to serve music and pictures for my own clients like my smartphone and laptop. On the smartphone I use the Qnap apps Qmusic and Qphoto. It works all fine, I just don't like the ability of the user "admin" to log in to the station.

I can block certain users completelly by the authentication rules in .htaccess. This works fine when accessing the station throught the web browser, but causes issues with the apps cause they don't expect an authenticaton like that.

Now my question: I would need an if-then-else procedure in the .htaccess file about like this:

`if user-agent is not "Qmusic" then
  <authenticate>
end if`

This should be ignored if the condition is not true. Can this be done somehow?

I have serched the internet for quite a while but did not fine anything sutiable.

thanks for your support.

Comment: which apache version are you using?

Comment: I use Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check out the Apache [`mod_authz_core`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html) documentation for this, specifically the [`Require env`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#requiredirectives) directive. Combining that referenced example with the one in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/865372/245518) allows you to set a variable based on user agent, then exempt that user agent from authentication.

Note that the referenced answer is for the older Apache 2.2 syntax, which is still available in 2.4 with the [`mod_access_compat`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_access_compat.html) module, but the newer syntax is preferred.

Apache 2.4 Example:

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent ^Qmusic no-auth

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Login"
AuthUserFile /path/to/htpasswd
Require valid-user
Require env no-auth
```

Note that multiple `Require` directives are implicitly contained in a `<RequireAny>` block, unless otherwise specified. This means the request must match either a valid user from `htpasswd` or whatever auth mechanism you choose, or the request must match the `no-auth` environmental variable, which we have set for the `Qmusic` user agent.

Comment: That looks already great AfroThundr. But do I understand this correctly: the authentication is required if the the user-agent IS NOT Qmusic? If the user-agent IS Qmusic, no authentication window is opened and the authentication code is ignored?
(I am not to deep into programing, but placing the code for authentication without any introduction and then the conditions at the end looks strange...)

Comment: Yes, due to how the `Require` directive works, that authentication block will succeed on one of two conditions: 1) A valid username/password is entered, or 2) The `no-auth` variable is set on the request. We set that variable for any user-agents matching "Qmusic". The end result is that any client connecting with the user-agent `Qmusic` will not have to authenticate. This syntax is typical of apache authentication blocks. You can find more examples in the apache documentation I linked.